# Search in Tableview ios

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar

I have below Nsdictionary

```
    enter {
    Image = "https://www.mysite.com/api/image/303";
    Title = "My App1";
    apptype = IPHONE;
    category = Productivity;
}

    {
    Image = "https://www.mysite.com/api/image/304";
    Title = "My App2";
    apptype = IPHONE;
    category = Productivity;
}
```

I want to search using title and category using Searchbar in UItableviw.Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the documentation with examples [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008225).

Please read that and start coding - when you have further questions, come back with more detailed questions.